# If else statement and else if statement

Tags: php

New in PHP
Any error from this statement?
I just want to display if price = 0 then free,
 else then display normal price,
else if empty of discount price do nothing maintain price,
else have discount price then display discount price.

```
<?php
    if($value->price_value == 0 || '' ){
        echo "Free";
    } else {
        echo $formatted_price;
    } else if(empty($discount_price)){
        echo '';
    }else{
        echo $discount_price;
    }
?>
```

`$discount_price` come from:

```
    $value->price_value * $value->discount_percent_amount ;
    echo $discount_price ;
```

Comment: Your logic is not clear.  The immediate problem with your code is that you can't have anything after the `else` condition.

Comment: How many `echo` statements do you expect/want to be evaluated here?

Comment: No need to be rude.Rather answer how many echos you want. It's a valid question that could track down a flaw in your approach. I think your pseudo code should be: `then if empty of discount...`. In your real code you don't need the `then`. That means you just need to delete the `else` before `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you are trying to do. But here is the correct syntax base on what you written above

```
<?php
        if($value->price_value == 0 || $value->price_value == '' ){
            echo "Free";
        } else {
            echo $formatted_price;
        } 
        if(empty($discount_price)){
            echo '';
        }else{
            echo $discount_price;
        }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
<?php
    // assuming $value->price_value is a numeric

    if($value->price_value > 0){ # check first if price greater than 0

        if ($discount_percent_amount > 0) { # discounted percent amount is greater than 0
            // calculate the discounted price
            echo $value->price_value * $value->discount_percent_amount ;
        }else{ # display product price
            echo $value->price_value;
        }
    }else{ # free product
        echo "Free";
    }
?>
```

Note: It would be better to filter all the used variables if numeric using the `is_numeric()` function in php before proceeding to the conditional statements.